# How to get average z location of selected vertices in python?

Tags: python, vertices

I want to get the average z location of selected vertices in python.
And I want to select the vertices by their location using a range like (any vertices that lie in the range from 1 to 2 in the x axis).

Comment: The average z location of selected **vertices**?

Comment: I mean to get the sum of the z location of the selected vertex over their number.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve - I assume you need something like: `z = [11, 1, 0]` `sum(z) / float(len(z))` right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bmesh module solutions for both tasks (edit-mode only so far):

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

loc = [v.co.z for v in bm.verts if v.select]
if loc:
    avg = sum(loc) / len(loc)
    print(avg)

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for v in bm.verts:
    if v.co.x < 2 and v.co.x > 1:
        v.select = True
bm.select_flush(True)
```

Comment: this work thanks,but can you tell why you write that
"if loc:".

Comment: @OmarAhmad just to test if loc list is not empty, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty

Comment: @poor so if it is empty I can 
else:
   print("List is empty.")
to inform the user to select something,thanks

Comment: As poor said, I want to check if the list is empty. If it was, an exception would be raised at the average location calculation (`sum` requires a non-empty sequence). You can handle the else-case too of course. If the code was surrounded in a function, you could also `if not loc: return`.

Answer (score 2):

This is for calculating the average Z of the selected vertices :

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT') 
obj = bpy.context.active_object
s = i= 0
for v in obj.data.vertices:
    if v.select :
        s += v.co[2]
        i += 1

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')     
a = s/i
print(a)
```

for selecting use the same loop and do a test :

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT') 
obj = bpy.context.active_object
max = 2
min = 1
for v in obj.data.vertices:
    if v.co[0] < max and v.co[0] > min :
        v.select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

Comment: This works too,thanks.but can you tell me what is "s = i= 0".

Comment: It's simply a shortcut that assigns 0 to both s and i - same as `s=0` `i=0`

Comment: Using counter variables if quite un-pythonic. It's nicer and possibly faster to use list comprehensions. Note that mode switches can be expensive. They are required in the standard API however. The Bmesh module does not require mode changes, but it comes with an overhead. It's worth to compare performance on low and high resolution meshes.

Comment: Possible divide by zero error here also, but helpful nonetheless.  Thanks!